# Print Bill in Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I want to print the Bill like super markets from UWP. I want to create a bill first then I need to fire command for printing. I am not sure about the format of the file, how should I manage it?

Comment: this is going to be highly dependent on the kind of printer you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the point of service API (POS) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/point-of-service

Or you can use the normal printer API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app